# Split string with letters and numbers like C420F140000

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, split

I have a string "`F12C429C420T160000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"`
that needs to be split on each letter so that it looks like F12 C429 C420 T16 and put each into an array.

This string is a fixed length of 90 and may have no error codes (all zeros) or one or more error codes.

All codes start with a letter followed by 2 to 3 digits.

All digits below 10 are preceded by a 0, such as 01.

I have tried some regex examples and they were on the slow side.

Any suggestions for doing this extraction efficiently in `VB.Net or C#`

Comment: Hello, what have you tried?

Comment: OP said he tried Regex, but have not shown them. Well. Words.

Comment: What's the desired result?

Comment: Have you tried something like `new Regex("([A-Z][0-9]{2,3})").Matches("F12C429C420T160000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")`?

Comment: Btw: OP said in the comments that the desired result is to have T16 as the last item.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using regular expression to resolve this.

Try pattern like

```
[A-Z][0-9]{2,3}
```

This will look for a Leading uppercase letter, with trailing digits.

However, as in your example this is not a perfect solution due to the underlying string.  For example, in your sample, the last code can be `T16` or `T160`.

If the list of error codes is finite, it might be better to create a lookup table instead.

If you are generating the list, it might be better to use a different padding character to remove the above ambiguity.

Following some further details in the comments :

Try

```
((E|F|T)[0-9]{2}|C[0-9]{3})
```

This will ensure that E/F/T are followed by two digits, while c is followed by 3. The ambiguity mention above is then removed.  Thus, your complete code might look something like

```
Regex expr = new Regex("((E|F|T)[0-9]{2}|C[0-9]{3})");
MatchCollection matches = expr.Matches("F12C429C420T160000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
foreach (Match matchedCode in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(matchedCode.Value);
}
```

Comment: +1 for noticing T16/T160 ambiguity

Comment: Btw. OP have just said in the comments that the desired result is to have T16 as the last item.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Thanks for the update, the OP should have clarified the details to begin with :)

Comment: @user3752477 Are they any other requirements?

Answer (score 2):

I would write a method for this. You could simply loop all characters and put all tokens in a list. Use `Char.IsDigit` or `Char.IsLetter`:

```
Public Shared Function SplitByLetter(text As String) As String()
    Dim list As New List(Of String)
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    For Each chr As Char In text
        If Char.IsLetter(chr) Then
            If sb.Length > 0 Then list.Add(sb.ToString())
            sb.Clear()
        End If
        sb.Append(chr)
    Next
    If sb.Length > 0 Then list.Add(sb.ToString())
    Return list.ToArray()
End Function
```

With your sample string:

```
Dim text As String = "F12C429C420T160000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
Dim tokens As String() = SplitByLetter(text)
For Each part As String In tokens
    Console.WriteLine(part)
Next
```

Output is:

```
F12
C429
C420
T160000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I don't know if the last token is correct, you haven't mentioned that. Maybe you want to stop when a token is longer than 3 characters, then change the `if`:

```
If sb.Length >= 4 OrElse Char.IsLetter(chr) Then
```

and the result is:

```
F12
C429
C420
T160
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
000
```

Comment: `All codes start with a letter followed by 2 to 3 digits.` <-- T1600 is 4 digits.

Comment: The last one s/b T16. I do have a really basic one that works, but is slower than yours works good except fpr last item, E,F and Ts are letter plus 2 digits, C is C plus 3 digits.

Comment: @Neolisk: you're right, it must be `If sb.Length >= 4` instead of `> 4`, corrected.

Comment: @user3752447: sorry, i've only just noticed that you've commented. Are the zeros always at the end? What is the rule which ends the error codes? Is the last error-code reached if there are at least two zeros following?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
    {    
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> words=new List<string>();                
            string word="";
            string str = "F12C429C420T16000000000000000000000000000000000000
                                     0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
            foreach (char ch in str)
            {
                if (char.IsLetter(ch))
                {
                    words.Add(word);
                    word = ch.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    word += ch.ToString();
                }
            }
            words.Add(word);
            words.RemoveAt(0);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

- Scan the string and count letters, or find out the number in any other way
- Preallocate an empty array of string with that size, all entries empty
- Run a for-loop that will scan indexes from 0 to end-of-string
- Inside that loop run a second smaller loop that will detect digit/letter edge
- upon detecting the edge, make a substring from last-letter upto the-edge and write it into next array entry

That's a rough sketch that will work. Variables and details intentionally excluded. This is manual and minimalistic approach, and will be hard to make faster without parallelization. You might also somethimes benefit from making the search and cutting lazy (on-demand) or localized (search only from index ... upto index ...) but that strongly depends on other bits of your system.

Comment: The strings are only 90 characters, so it will be hard to make faster *with* parallelization.

Comment: @Gabe - Strings have 90 characters, but if there are millions of the strings, then parallelization _may_ be reasonable. Again we're into bits that OP didn't provide.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should work. My only concern is how do you know the difference between T16 and T160?

```
string s = "F12C429C420T160000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        string result = "";
        foreach (char c in s.TrimEnd('0'))
        {
            if( c > 64)result+=c;
            else result+=' '+c;
        }
        string[] final = result.Split(' ');
```